# React hook form - populate select many options array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, side-effects, react-hook-form

I am trying to use `react-hook-form` to make a select menu from which multiple options can be chosen.

I have a database array with the records I want to use to populate the select menu.

In `formik`, I have successfully used this `componentDidMount` async method to get the records from the database and give them to the select method. I can't get that to work with react hooks.

```
state = {
      options: [],
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        let options = [];
        await fsDB.collection("abs_for_codes").get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
            options.push({
                value: doc.data().title.replace(/( )/g, ''),
                label: doc.data().title + ' - ABS ' + doc.id
            });
            });
        });
        this.setState({
            options
        });
    }
```

I've then been able to use a const in my select menu to get the drop down menu items as follows:

```
options={options}
```

I can't get that to work in react hook form and I'm trying to learn how to `useEffect`, which I think are supposed to replace this approach.

However, I can't figure out how to start with this.

My current form is in a fragment (so that I can keep using antd in the rest of my front end) that has:

```
import React from "react";
import useForm from "react-hook-form";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { StateMachineProvider, createStore } from "little-state-machine";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { useStateMachine } from "little-state-machine";
import { fsDB, firebase, settings } from "../../../firebase";

import updateAction from "./updateAction";
import "./styles.css";


createStore({
  data: {}
});


const General = props => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();
  const { action } = useStateMachine(updateAction);
  const onSubit = data => {
    action(data);
    props.history.push("./ProposalMethod");
  };

  return (

      <React.Fragment>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubit)}>
          <h2>Part 1: General</h2>
          <label>
            Title
            <input 
              type="text" 
              name="title"  
              placeholder="The title " 
              ref={register({ required: true })} 
            />
          </label>
          {errors.title && <p id="titleError">A title is required</p>}

          <label>
            Subtitle
            <input 
              type="text" 
              name="subtitle"  
              placeholder="An optional subtitle" 
              ref={register} 
            />
          </label>

          <label>Select your fields </label>
          <Select 
            name="field" 
            placeholder="Select" 
            options={options}
          />
          <input type="submit" value="next" />

        </form>
      </React.Fragment>  
  );
}; 

export default withRouter(General);
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

I can't figure out how to replace the `componentDidMount` with something that works with react-hook-form.

Comment: Any chance you can provide a codesandbox for your issue?

Comment: Hi Bruce - here is a sandbox - I have commented out the calls on the db - I can't share access to the db, but I have a set of values and labels in there that I want to populate in the select: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-wizard-form-sl3po

Answer (score 0):

Using `useEffect` to perform the same behavior when using `componentDidMount`, you should call the same actions inside the useEffect method, but creating a function inside it, then call it:

```
useEffect(() => {
    populateOptions() => {
        let options = [];
            await fsDB.collection("abs_for_codes").get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
                options.push({
                    value: doc.data().title.replace(/( )/g, ''),
                    label: doc.data().title + ' - ABS ' + doc.id
                });
            });
        });
    }
    populateOptions();
}, []);
```

Then you can use `options={options}` in your `<select>`.
Just remember that using hooks your options should be using `useState` hook:

```
const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);
```